# How to set initial value using useState hook from Redux store?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to make an edit form for my model and set the initial values of the form to the values of the model. I've tried:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { getPost, destroyPost } from '../../actions/posts'
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";


const Edit = ({ match }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const history = useHistory()
  const post = useSelector(state => state.post)
  const postId = match.params.id

  const handleClick = () => {
    dispatch(destroyPost(postId))
    history.push("/")
  }
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    title: post.attributes.title,
    body: post.attributes.body
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getPost(postId))
  }, [])

 

  if (!post) { return <div>Loading...</div>}

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(formData)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>  
          {/* form stuff */}
      </form>
    </div>
  )
  

}

export default Edit
```

Basically, I'm taking the post object from my redux store and using those values to set my state in my component. This, of course, is loading before my api comes back with my post data so I get undefined.

I've tried setting state under

```
  if (!post) { return <div>Loading...</div>}
```

but I get an infinite loop.

I've even tried something like

```
useState({
    title: post? post.attributes.title : '',
    body: post? post.attributes.body : ''
  }
```

But that's not working.

In other apps, I used a kind of container element for my form and passed the model as a prop, but I'm not sure if I need to do that or if there's a better way.

Comment: have you tired to use optional chain ? `title: post?.attributes?.titile ?? "your initial value"` ?

Comment: why do you need to put your post into a state, it is already in your state (redux)? Also check if useEffect is called only once, event better put your postId as a dependancy

Comment: Nitkia, I needed to put in my form's state to set the default values of my edit form so my form is prepopulated when the user uses it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your initial value of post is `null` then you need to guard your initial state data with `optional Chaining` this as

```
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    title: post?.attributes?.title || '',
    body: post?.attributes?.body || ''
  })
```

You are firing the API call when the component is mounted which will update the post state in the store . What you need is another use Effect which will watch for the post and fires when it changes .

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(post){
      setFormData({
      title: post?.attributes?.title || '',
      body: post?.attributes?.body || ''
})
 }
}, [post])
```

Add post as the dependency in the `useEffect`.

Comment: This works! Thanks. Can you tell me what the name of that post? synatx is called so I can read more about it?

Comment: `?.` this is called as optional chaining - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining